# How to convert "index" to a "string"?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a working example code:

```
data = {'name': ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Jack', 'Hack', 'David', 'Marry', 'Wansi', 'Sidy', 'Jason', 'Even'],

        'age': [25, 32, 18, np.nan, 15, 20, 41, np.nan, 37, 32],

        'gender': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],

        'isMarried': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=labels)
print(df)
print("---------------------------")
obj = df[df["age"]>40].index.format()
print("obj is",type(obj))
```

I hope obj as a string (), but the above result is list().
What should I do to correct it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put obj = obj[0] and it will then become a string

```
data = {'name': ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Jack', 'Hack', 'David', 'Marry', 'Wansi', 'Sidy', 'Jason', 'Even'],

        'age': [25, 32, 18, np.nan, 15, 20, 41, np.nan, 37, 32],

        'gender': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],

        'isMarried': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=labels)
print(df)
print("---------------------------")
obj = df[df["age"]>40].index.format()
obj = obj[0]
print("obj is",type(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = df[df["age"]>40].index.format()[0]
print("obj is",obj,type(obj))
```

```
obj is g <class 'str'>
```